# Dependency issue with sherlockbar_support lib

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to add a action sherlock bar library into my project and getting error i.e:

> Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

can anyone help me out from this?????

**@GrIsHu here are the error :**

```
**[2014-01-30 10:17:12-DemoXYZ] Path: D:\Workspace ACSD\workspace\sherlock library\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ]     Length: 556198
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ]     SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ] Path: D:\Workspace ACSD\workspace\DemoXYZ\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ]     Length: 621451
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ]     SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies**
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the your project might contains the `android-support-V4` jar and the sherlock library also contains the same jar file added into the library and that is why the jar dependency issue occurs.

Your project is not able to get that which jar file it should refer to. Just try to remove the jar file which you have added in your project and then clean and build your project again.

Comment: i had done with this but still its giving the same error...

Comment: @user3243147 Can you show me a screen shot of you project how you have added the library with your whole error ?

Comment: sorry i cant give the scrn shot

but here are the errors..

[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ] Path: D:\Workspace ACSD\workspace\sherlock library\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ]  Length: 556198
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ]  SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 -DemoXYZ] Path: D:\Workspace ACSD\workspace\DemoXYZ\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ]  Length: 621451
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ]  SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-01-30 10:17:12 - DemoXYZ] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies